# Jquery to check if an input has a specific name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there any function to check if an input has a specific name in jquery, like we check the existense of a class using `hasClass()`?

For example if I have an input

`<input type="checkbox" class="col_control" checked="checked" name="sr_column" data-columnno="0" />`

so that I can check `hasName("sr_column")` and it returns true

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
el.name == 'text'
```

No need for any jQuery! If you do have a jQuery object, use `jq_el[0].name == 'text'` instead.

Of course you can also use jQuery to access this, using either `jq_el.prop('name')` or `jq_el.attr('name')` (it's available both as a property and an attribute).

If you want `jq_el.hasName(...)`, you can define the function like this:

```
$.fn.hasName = function(name) {
    return this.name == name;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this also

```
 var name = $("#id").attr("name");
```

OR

```
 var name = $("#id").prop("name");


if(name=="sr_column")
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I was doing already but the method didn't seem OK to me... So just a +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, one can also use `$.filter()` on the jQuery objects and check the length of the list, e.g.

```
var $inputs = $("input");
if ($inputs.filter("[name=text]").length > 0) {
    // do something here
}
```